# Qbs support on MacOS with M1

Tags: x86-64, apple-m1, qbs

I'm trying to build my project (which I can build successfully on `intel`) on my Mac with M1 chip.
I have same version of qbs (1.22.1) on M1 nad intel, but on M1 parsing my qbs file ends with enigmatic error during parsing `CppApplication`:

```
CppApplication {
   name: "TestProject"
   .
   .
}
```

```
Error while handling product `TestProject`
Product `TestProject` had errors and was disabled.
```

I have no clue what this error could be. Anyone has any idea ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are building with Qt Creator? Sometimes the actual error message does not show up in the issues pane (or is difficult to see among all the follow-up errors). If you don't see it in "General Messages" either, try building on the command line. You should get more helpful output there.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! You were right, building in command line gives more info. I found out that I have incorrect path `toolchainInstallPath` to the compiler in my `qbs profile`. 
Problem solved ! thanks again!